# Intercept create process in embedded python?

Tags: python, subprocess, fork

I'm going to use embedded python interpreter in my iOS app.

Is there any possibility to intercept child processes calls like `Popen`?

```
proc = Popen(
        command,
        stdin=stdin,
        stdout=stdout,
        stderr=stderr,
        cwd=cwd)
out = proc.communicate()
```

In ios creating subprocesses is prohibited and i'd like to execute my code (like forwarding call to my static lib) instead.

Comment: `import subprocess; subprocess.Popen = YourPopen` at the start (sitecustomize).

Comment: what is it? i'd like to have c callback invoked if subprocess.Popen is invoked in Python script which is interpreted by embedded Python interpreter

Comment: YourPopen maybe any Python callable. In particular, it can call your C callback. Modules are global in Python. If you monkey-patch subprocess module then any script that runs in the same interpreter later will see the patched version.

Comment: ok, now i understand i can redefine it with my impl. How can i get my c callback invoked from my impl?

Comment: ctypes module allows to call C functions from Python

Comment: after reading about `ctypes` i'm thinking it's working but not the best way for embedded python. i've embedded python interpreter in my app. i have the sources of python and i can re/compile it if necessary. it's better to modify python source c file where subprocess is created. or use probably existing solution for intercepting script functions if exists

Comment: you could also define the Python callable using C API; it might be unnecessary verbose. Also look at how `gevent.monkey.patch_all()` or `pyximport.install()` (cython) monkey-patch python.